# Ubuntu File System Partition

Tags: partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 onto an external hard drive. When I looked in the disk, it showed 2 partitions, File system partition 1 & 2, both partitions are relatively small. So I was wondering, what are these two partitions, what do they do and do I need to expand them?

Thanks.

P.S. Picture of what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wWVI.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition 1 is an EFI partition. Most modern computers have one. Windows uses an EFI partition too. You can consider it to be the first part of the boot process

Partition 2 is a boot partition. In this instance it handles the preliminaries of accessing and booting your LUKS install

You won’t need to alter the size of either of them. You won’t save data there although the contents might get updated the space requirements will not change much. You will probably find there is quite a high percentage  of space unused currently.